# Changing the World Position of a Child Object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Is there a way in Three.js to change the world position of a child object?

My ultimate goal is to:

1) Detach the child from the parent (without it's location changing)

2) Move the parent to a different location

3) Reattach the child (without it's location changing)

In my code, the 'child' is actually a group of objects (and I'm looking to keep each in the same world position)

Currently, I have achieved 1 and 2 in the following way:

```
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
vector.setFromMatrixPosition( child.matrixWorld );
grandParent.remove( parent );
scene.add( parent );
parent.children[0].position = vector;
```

I've tried to reverse the above process by storing the matrixWorld, and updating it to the stored value, but was unsuccessful. I know that altering the matrixWorld is ill-advised, but it's the only method that has proven fruitful.

Comment: See if you can use the following utilities: `THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child, parent, scene );` and `THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child, scene, parent );`

Comment: I've tried using these utilities unsuccessfully, but I'm also not 100% certain on how they work. In my case, I'm creating a group of objects (i.e. objGroup). Adding those to another object (i.e. parent). For my purposes, do I need to ever work directly with objGroup's children? 

I feel as though this may be relevant, and right now am on a bus. I'll post an update when I get home.

Comment: Once again you have answered my question. Thank you @WestLangley. I had to use `group.add(child)` to create the group of objects. After that I used `THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child, scene, parent)`, which worked perfectly.

Comment: Would it work better if instead another parent was made, and then the two children moved freely, or even kept the hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can detach the child from the parent, transform the parent, and the reattach the child.

The method to use to do that is:

```
parent.attach( object );
```

which adds `object` as a child of `parent`, while maintaining the object's world transform.

three.js r.113