# Three.js add an object to a group but keep global position/rotation/scale as it was

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, three.js

I want to move an object from one group (or world/scene) to another group, but keep it's global transformation intact. Basically, I don't want to see the object change.

basically, something like this:

```
//store current world transformation
var origWorldMatrix = myObject.matrixWorld.clone();

//move object to a group (that is positioned and rotated arbitrarily)
someGroup.add( myObject );

//restore previous world transformation
myObject.matrixWorld.copy( origWorldMatrix );
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I guess because the world matrix is always updated the next frame, based on the local position/rotation/scale properties. 
I've tried to use this with matrixAutoUpdate = false, but that doesn't seem to work either.

The result I am trying to accomplish seems like something that should be simple to do, so I hope I am missing something obvious. Can anybody give me a clue on how do do this?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441223/changing-the-world-position-of-a-child-object-in-three-js/24458457#24458457 Study the source code of `attach()` and `detach()` so you understand what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for. You'd think that in all my searches, I would have stumbled upon that answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: You can use the built-in method `Object3D.attach()`:

```
// add object as a child of parent, while maintaining the object's world transform

parent.attach( object );
```

three.js r.109

Comment: WL you are the Three.Angel :-)