# regrouping objects in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

/********************Updated 6/25/2016 **********************************/
having isssues with changing orientation of sides on rubiks cube... example located here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMMRKJ

thank you West Langely for your suggestion. I've attempted to implement.  here is the example here it is   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMMRKJ

so again I am originally creating 3 sides of a rubiks cube that rotate on the z axis.

```
 for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                for (var z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                    var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(gpboyw);
                    var cubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2.9, 2.9, 2.9);
                    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, faceMaterial);
                    var xp = x * 3 - 3;
                    var yp = y * 3 - 3;
                    var zp = z * 3 - 3;
                    cube.position.set(xp, yp, zp)
                    if (z === 0) {
                        side1.add(cube);
                    }
                    if (z === 1) {
                        side2.add(cube);
                    }
                    if (z === 2) {
                       side3.add(cube);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

then when clicking any of the sides I use a raycaster identify the side and rotate it on its z axis 90 degrees.

I then added radio buttons to allow you to switch orientation (rotating a column style side around a z axis to rotating a row style side around the x axis.  this was not workign and Mr. Langely suggested using the scene utility detach and attach to unattach my small cubes from column style sides and reattach them to row style sides but something is not working.  if you go to the example and switch the orientation radio buttons you can see it is not working properly.

here was my attempt at detach reattach.

```
$('input[type=radio][name=orientation]').change(function () {
            controls.changeOrientation = true
            if (this.value == 'vertical') {
                controls.vertical = true;
                controls.horizontal = false;
            }
            else if (this.value == 'horizontal') {
                controls.vertical = false;
                controls.horizontal = true;
            }


            var cubes = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < side1.children.length; i++) {
                cubes.push(side1.children[i]);
                //THREE.SceneUtils.detach(side1.children[i], side1, scene);
            }


            for (var i = 0; i < side2.children.length; i++) {
                cubes.push(side2.children[i]);
                //THREE.SceneUtils.detach(side2.children[i], side2, scene);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < side3.children.length; i++) {
                cubes.push(side3.children[i]);
                //THREE.SceneUtils.detach(side3.children[i], side3, scene);
            }
            console.log('num of cubes ' + cubes.length)


            THREE.SceneUtils.detach(side1, totalCube, scene);
            THREE.SceneUtils.detach(side2, totalCube, scene);
            THREE.SceneUtils.detach(side3, totalCube, scene);

            for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
                var mycube = cubes[i];
                console.log(' position ' + mycube.position.x + '.' + mycube.position.y + '.' + mycube.position.z)

                if (controls.vertical) {
                    if (mycube.position.z == -3) {
                        THREE.SceneUtils.attach(mycube, scene, side1);
                    }
                    if (mycube.position.z == 0) {
                        THREE.SceneUtils.attach(mycube, scene, side2);
                    }
                    if (mycube.position.z == 3) {
                        THREE.SceneUtils.attach(mycube, scene, side3);
                    }
                } else {


                    if (mycube.position.x == -3) {
                        THREE.SceneUtils.attach(mycube, scene, side1);

                    }
                    if (mycube.position.x == 0) {
                        THREE.SceneUtils.attach(mycube, scene, side2);
                    }
                    if (mycube.position.x == 3) {
                        THREE.SceneUtils.attach(mycube, scene, side3);
                    }
                }
            }

            THREE.SceneUtils.attach(side1, scene, totalCube);
            THREE.SceneUtils.attach(side2, scene, totalCube);
            THREE.SceneUtils.attach(side3, scene, totalCube);

            controls.changeOrientation = false;

        });
```

/*********************Here is the Original Post ********************************/

I've been working on a Rubiks cube.  here is what I have so far   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMMRKJ

go to the example and uncomment the line   `// side1h.add(cube);`to see the problem

you can rotate the cube sides left click clockwise, right click counter clockwise.

you can move the camera by click drag.  you can zoom the camera with the mouse wheel.

so the rubiks cube is made of many cubes. and then I group each side so that I can rotate the side.

```
for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
            var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(gpboyw);
            var cubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2.9, 2.9, 2.9);
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, faceMaterial);
            var xp = x * 3 - 3;
            var yp = y * 3 - 3;
            var zp = z * 3 - 3;
            cube.position.set(xp, yp, zp)
            scene.add(cube);
            if (z === 0) {
                side1.add(cube);
            }
            if (z === 1) {
                side2.add(cube);
            }
            if (z === 2) {
               side3.add(cube);
            }
            if (x === 0) {
               // side1h.add(cube);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

then I use a raycaster to see which side you've clicked on and I rotate that side. is working ok.  as you can see in the example.   however the problems comes when you uncomment the last group there side1h  (this is for horizontal)  when I attempt to group horizontal and vertical I think the child can only belong to one group?  not sure?  is there a way to ungroup and regroup after each rotation is done?

Comment: Likey this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364409/three-js-add-an-object-to-a-group-but-keep-global-position-rotation-scale-as-it/35365349#35365349

Comment: thank you for your suggestion I am having a bit of difficulty implementing your suggested solution. I have updated my original post, and my example with my attempt.  thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I can't debug your code for you... Start with 27 cubes as children of the scene. When it is time to rotate, set 9 cubes as children of a pivot, and rotate the pivot. When rotation completes, reset the 9 cubes as children of the scene.