# How to maintain world position, rotation and scale when grouping objects>

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add one object to another while maintaining it's rotation, position, and scale. I am trying to get mesh4 to be in the same position as mesh3 when grouped with mesh. 
Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3r5eq4s0/1/

This is what I am currently doing to try to rectify while grouping.

```
mesh4.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(mesh4.quaternion, mesh.quaternion.inverse());
mesh4.scale.set(mesh4.scale.x * (1 / mesh.scale.x), mesh4.scale.y * (1 / mesh.scale.y), mesh4.scale.z * (1 / mesh.scale.z));
mesh4.position = mesh.worldToLocal(mesh4.getWorldPosition());
```

Is there a way to do this as I seem to have the rotation and scaling working ok, but the position is off.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364409/three-js-add-an-object-to-a-group-but-keep-global-position-rotation-scale-as-it/35365349#35365349

Comment: Thank you, I tried a whole bunch of search terms but that answer didn't come up!