# How to apply parent transforms in the same order to child elements?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my application users can select 3d objects on a workplane in order to scale, move or rotate these elements together using a "transformation" container, i.e. an `Object3D`, that groups all transformations and applies these to all children. When deselecting the child elements, the parent container's transformation should be transferred to all children which in turn are removed from the transform container and added back to the main scene object.

However, the child elements are transformed differently when in the transform container where the transformation is applied to the container and not the element itself, e.g. when applying a scale transform to the container with a child having a local rotation then it looks that the local rotation is applied first and afterwards the container's scale transform.
When applying parent's transformations to all children with `child.applyMatrix(parent.matrixWorld)` and putting the child back to the scene container the transformation order is reversed.

1. container[scale]{child[rotation]} -> order: rotation, scale
2. `child.applyMatrix(parent.matrixWorld)`
3. child[scale,rotation]{} -> order: scale, rotation

What would I have to do with the child elements to get the same transformation order and appearance result?

**Update:**
I figured out how to correctly apply the parent's transformations to the child. I used the same code from `Object3D.applyMatrix()`:
`child.matrix.multiplyMatrices(parent_old.matrixWorld, child.matrix);` but also set `child.matrixAutoUpdate = false;` and left out `child.matrix.decompose(child.position, child.quaternion, child.scale);`

Therefore, `matrixAutoUpdate = true` does not work. `Matrix4.decompose()` somehow changes the matrix values before setting `position`, `scale` and `quaternion` thus in my example case the shearing transform of the inner child applied by parent's scale transform is reset.

To me this looks inconsistent since such kind of transformation is allowed and displayed when nested object transformations are used. Furthermore, using `child.applyMatrix(parent.matrixWorld)` to apply parent transforms to a child object (what I have quite often read as a solution for that purpose) would not be correct. I don't know if this is an intended behavior of three.js. If so, can someone explain why?

Comment: (1) It is better to show a simple live example to demonstrate the issue. I am guessing what your issue is... (2) See [this three.js post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3845). (3) Also, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364409/three-js-add-an-object-to-a-group-but-keep-global-position-rotation-scale-as-it/35365349#35365349).

Comment: Many thanks @WestLangley  This is exactly the issue. Obviously I stumbled upon this non-uniform scale case you mentioned in your post (2). For my use case I need this non-uniform scale. Can I keep using my concept when switching to manually setting the matrix (`matrixAutoUpdate = false`)?

Comment: Yes, but understand that if you do so, methods that set the position, quaternion, or scale directly will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @WestLangley and the provided [THREE.js post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3845) and [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364409/three-js-add-an-object-to-a-group-but-keep-global-position-rotation-scale-as-it/35365349#35365349) I figured out a solution for me. The issue I experienced is due to THREE.js' design concept of

> [representing an object's transform with a position, quaternion/rotation, and scale -- applied in the order S-R-T.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3845)

Simply put, when applying a non-uniform scale on an object's parent this order is changed and cannot be mapped from an object's transform matrix back to the convenient `position`, `scale` and `quaternion` properties.

My solution is to

> [represent the object transform with a matrix only.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3845)

That means that I set my 3d objects' `matrixAutoUpdate = false` and do not use the mentioned position, scale, quaternion properties anymore. Instead, I set any transformations on the object's matrix directly by utilizing `THREE.Matrix4` methods only.

Comment: Yeah, that is a big problem indeed. Can you share precisely what `THREE.Matrix4` methods you use, in what order and whether there are drawback to those as well?