# Move child from one parent to another in threejs while keeping world coordinates the same

Tags: three.js

I am trying to take a child from one parent that is off centre and perhaps rotated; however, when I take a child from this node and add it as a child for a different node, I would like to update some of the basic properties like position, scale and rotation.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364409/three-js-add-an-object-to-a-group-but-keep-global-position-rotation-scale-as-it

Comment: Thanks will try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using the detach and then attach on the object will work.

**WATCH OUT:** Both methods do NOT have the same parameter order.

```
// remove child from parent and add it to scene
THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child, parent, scene );

// remove child from scene and add it to parent
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child, scene, parent );
```

Answer (score 2):

`THREE.SceneUtils` is deprecated. You should use:

```
// remove child from parent and add it to scene
scene.attach( child );

// remove child from scene and add it to parent
parent.attach( child );
```