# Change parent of component and keep position

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

I am using [AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js) and have a sphere positioned in the marker component.

```
<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded="" arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;">
        <a-marker markerhandler id="marker" emitevents="true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" preset="hiro">
            <a-sphere id="sphere" color="green" radius="0.3" position="0 1 0" ></a-sphere>
        </a-marker>
        <!-- use this <a-entity camera> to support multiple-markers, otherwise use <a-marker-camera> instead of </a-marker>-->
        <a-entity camera="" id="camera">
                <a-entity geometry="primitive: plane; height: 0.1; width: 0.1" position="0.4 -0.2 -1"
                material="color: gray; opacity: 0.5"></a-entity>
                <a-entity id="sphere-button" geometry="primitive: plane; height: 0.1; width: 0.1" position="-0.4 -0.2 -1"
                material="color: green; opacity: 0.5"></a-entity>
        </a-entity>
    </a-scene>  
  </body>
```

When *#sphere-button* is clicked, the sphere should dettach from  
and  attach to the camera. 
During the relocation in the DOM, the position should stay the 
same, but it does not. I tried this:

```
let v = new THREE.Vector3();
v.copy(sphere.object3D.position);
sphere.object3D.localToWorld(v);
camera.object3D.worldToLocal(v);
sphere.parentNode.removeChild(entity);
camera.appendChild(sphere);
entity.setAttribute('position', v);
```

How do i correctly translate the position between the two parents **a-camera** and **a-marker**?

Comment: Have a look at `.attach()` and `.detach()` methods of [`THREE.SceneUtils`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/utils/SceneUtils.attach).

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364409/three-js-add-an-object-to-a-group-but-keep-global-position-rotation-scale-as-it

Comment: I get the error `THREE.SceneUtils has been moved to /examples/js/utils/SceneUtils.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reparenting, I'd do it at three.js level for now and not use the DOM. Detaching and attaching on DOM atm will re-init everything and would be a mess.

```
let v = new THREE.Vector3();
v.copy(sphere.object3D.position);
sphere.object3D.localToWorld(v);
camera.object3D.worldToLocal(v);
camera.object3D.add(sphere.object3D);
sphere.object3D.position.copy(v);
```

Comment: This code has a typo. `camera.object3D.add(sphere);` should be `camera.object3D.add(sphere.object3D);`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a different approach, using `object3D.attach` (as suggested by @prisoner849 in a comment) to get the position, rotation, etc. of the Three object related to the intended parent, and then cloning the entity using that position, rotation,... under the intended parent (finally, removing the original entity).

You can have a look at a component implementing this approach in [this answer to "AFrame: reparenting an element keeping its world position, rotation"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65554657/2075265).